# how can I input a file and run an asynchronously command on it in python?

Tags: python, input, subprocess

I'm trying to write a script that asks for an input file and then runs some command on it. when I run the script it askes me for filename and when I give the file (e.g example.bam) then I get this error:

> NameError: name 'example.bam' is not defined

I tried many things but I couldn't fix it. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

This is my comand:

```
from subprocess import call
filename = input ("filename: ");
with open (filename, "r") as a:
    for command in ("samtools tview 'a' /chicken/chick_build2.1_unmasked.fa",):
        call(command, shell=True)
```

This is a short version of my command: it has to do much more stuff. I'm also thinking to input 4-6 files at same time (perhaps this information is helpful to clarify my intentions).

Comment: I should add that the file that I'm trying to input is in BAM format (a binary format)

Comment: The error you posted gives the impression that you are using the `example` variable somewhere, but it is not yet defined (in the part you posted, at least). Do you have any idea where that variable is used, and if so, could you post it?

Comment: the "example" is the file that I put for input! so when I run this script it ask me for a file and then I put example.bam and then it gives me the error that NameError: name 'example.bam' is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`. So what your script currently tries to do is interpret your input ("example", in your case), and execute as if it were a statement in your script. For user input (and might I simply say "for any input" -- unless you know what you're doing), always use the `raw_input` function.

So, to solve it, replace `input` with `raw_input`:

```
filename = raw_input("filename: ")
```

Comment: now I get another error that the file dose not exist!                 > open: No such file or directory

Comment: Two things to check: is the filename you entered correct? Is the file available on the current path?

Comment: both of the answer is yes! it's correct and it's in the same folder so I just put the name! and I even tried it with the whole path from the root!

Comment: I'm absolutely certain that this: `filename = raw_input("Filename: ")\nwith open(filename, 'r') as f:\n    for line in f.readlines():\n        print line.strip()` (replace `\n` with newlines) will print the contents of a file in the current directory. Are you sure that the files you run with the `call` function aren't the culprit?

Comment: I run this script that you told me now with my file and I got:\n  with open (Filename, 'r') as f:\n
NameError: name 'Filename' is not defined\n and at first I thought it's the same problem (that the call function are the culprit) but the I call the same command and I just replace the "a" with file name! and it works perfectly! can it be because it's a binary file!

Comment: `Filename` in that line should be lowercase: `filename`.

Comment: ok this command print line.strip() works! so it should be with the call function! thanks for your time!

Comment: Not to sound harsh, but could you first try to get the example I posted in the commands working? Create a new folder; create a file `test.py` with the contents I posted; create a file `file.txt` with some lines in it; open a command prompt and cd to the new directory; run `python test.py`, and enter `file.txt`. If that is working, make sure all your files for your own environment are in the same directory - and execute it from that directory. Then, remove the `shell=True` from the `call` method and see what that does.

Comment: So I tried the command that you wrote in the comment and it worked! with my file (there was a stupid type mistake) but when I try the same command with my `call command` it dose not work! and it gives me the error of no file or directory exist! I can't remove the `shell=True` because samtools requires shell for it's function! so I think what I need is to find a way to use the file as the input in the call command! Because the call command work's perfectly if I use the real filename (e.g `example.bam`) not the input one (e.g in this cas `a` (I hope you understand what  I'm trying to say))

Comment: This is getting more like a debug session, so lets try to wrap it up. I think you want to execute `samtool` on a file the user entered, right? If so, just do this: `filename = raw_input("filename: ")\ncmd = "samtools tview %s /chicken/chick_build2.1_unmasked.fa" % filename\nprint cmd\ncall(cmd, shell=True)`. It then first prints the filename, and then executes that string as the command. I think what remains is that you are building your command string incorrectly.